# Unity Update method same key input twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a dialog system on unity where the user has options to select from and either gets a response via a text field or gets more options to choose from.

At first i have 3 options. These 3 options belong to a script and another 2 options belong to another which are both running simultaneously. Each option has an int index(first option = 0 , second option = 1 etc..). I have made it so that if i press on option 1, the index becomes 3 to go to the fourth option.
As i have put everything in Update to wait for key input by user, whenever the user presses Enter, it gets executed from both of the scripts so it enters both statements at once.

Whats happening basically when i select option 1, im getting the response of option 4 instantly because when i press enter it gets executed from both scripts

How can i make it so that when i press enter for option 1 it ignores the other statement please. Screenshots below.

```
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Return)) {

            if (indexConversation == 0) {
                Debug.Log("first Option");


               // GameObject.Find("Scripts2").SetActive(true);

                telResponse.text = "Response 1"; 
                Conv1Controller.Conv1showConversation = true;
                indexConversation = 3;
                Debug.Log (indexConversation);

            } else if (indexConversation == 1) {

                Debug.Log("second Option");
                telResponse.text = "Response 2";
                StartCoroutine(responseTwoFollowedbySix ());
            }

            else if (indexConversation == 2) {

                Debug.Log("third Option");
                telResponse.text = "Response 3";
                StartCoroutine(responseThreeFollowedbyFourFollowedbySeven ());
            }

            showConversation = false;

        }
```

The other script (option 4 and 5)

```
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            if (DialogueController.indexConversation == 3)
            {
                Debug.Log("Fourth Option");
                telResponse.text = "Response 4";


            }


            if (DialogueController.indexConversation == 4)
            {

                Debug.Log("Option 5");
                telResponse.text = "Response 5";
            }

            //Conv1showConversation = false;


        }
```

Comment: Don't post your code as a screenshots. Copy and post that code in your question.

Comment: Is there no way you could put them in the same script?

Comment: i put them in seperate scripts because they have the same methods just option 4 and 5 differently and also i cant have 2 OnGUI's right?

Comment: You are not supposed to be using **OnGUI**. Do not use **OnGUI**.  I suggest you paste the complete script since it looks like you are doing lots of things the wrong way

Comment: I would highly recommend having a central input processor for this to avoid complexity. You can have the central script call functions in other scripts if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your first script has a `indexConversation` variable and your second script seems to refer to it using `DialogueController.indexConversation`, I feel like this variable is a `public static int` one. In this situation you could simply do something like this:

**First script**

```
[SerializeField]
private YOUR_OTHER_SCRIPT_CLASS otherScript;

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return))
{
    showConversation = false;
    switch(indexConversation)
    {
        case 0:
            Debug.Log("first Option");
            telResponse.text = "Response 1"; 
            Conv1Controller.Conv1showConversation = true;
            indexConversation = 3;
            Debug.Log (indexConversation);
            break;

        case 1:
            Debug.Log("second Option");
            telResponse.text = "Response 2";
            StartCoroutine(responseTwoFollowedbySix ());
            break;

        case 2:
            Debug.Log("third Option");
            telResponse.text = "Response 3";
            StartCoroutine(responseThreeFollowedbyFourFollowedbySeven ());
            break;

        default:
            otherScript.ReturnKeyPressed();
            break;
    }
    showConversation = false;
}
```

Here I added a variable to reference your other script and used a `switch` instruction to avoid the many `if` and `else if`.
Also if the value of `indexConversation` is not 1, 2 or 3, you ask for your other scrip to do something.

**Other script**

```
public void ReturnKeyPressed()
{
    switch(DialogueController.indexConversation)
    {
        case 3:
            Debug.Log("Fourth Option");
            telResponse.text = "Response 4";
            break;

        case 4:
            Debug.Log("Option 5");
            telResponse.text = "Response 5";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In this script, there is no more `if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return))` since the input detection will be made in the first script and send to this script if needed.

**P.-S.**

- As @Programmer said, you should never use `OnGUI()` for anything else than debugging. This method is really heavy as it's called many times per frame (which is useless) and you can use [Unity UI System](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) to work with UI easily.
- As @Nabren suggested, if your system is more complexe than this simple case, you should really change the way it's made and have an input manager class that get inputs and send them to the appropriate scripts.

*Hope this helps,*

Answer (score 0):

You should really think about storing your conversations into a Model that have a link to responses and responses can link to specific "FollowUp" conversation. This way you can write the script as agnostic as possible. You just give it a response and it knows how to handle it. Each response would get its own "ResponseView" Script which takes in a response model and could add button listeners or key listeners for press events and then upon receiving the correct input would load the next conversation using its current response model. Writing specific methods in code to tell your responses where they need to go is very very fragile and will not scale well at all.